# iOS Certificates doesnt allow app uploads

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I have an apple developer program register to my company. Under the iOS Certificates, I see the organization name being repeated 3x and a team member/admin under each.(Is it right to say having 3 distribution certificates). This is giving me problems in uploading my app build's using fastlane. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is? I'm having a hard time understanding this and am still very new to this.

Comment: Do you already have any apps (or provisioning profiles) using the 3 certificates?

Comment: @MatanGold I have an app each for the 2 certificates. Another one is of the developers